# Does the iPhone 6 get hot enough during normal use for an aftermarket case to leave permanent marks on the finish?

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 6 plus whose casing is made of anodized aluminium and stainless steel.  This was recently marked by a case (see picture below). The makers of the case are insisting that the phone has overheated and caused the problem. I was wondering how hot does the phone have to get to mark this anodized aluminium or stainless steel finish?

Is it possible for the phone to get hot enough without it tripping the phone and turning it off until it cools?

[image]

Comment: Anodized aluminum and stainless steel are two different materials. Not sure what you mean "marked by a case." Do you have a picture?

Comment: @Air I'm Sorry my bad. I'm just going by the description on Apples page. These are the only pics I have sorry. http://imgur.com/iKZ9AeH
http://imgur.com/1URNq5r

Comment: From the below link i understand the back case is made of anodized aluminium https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201296. In general, as per anodising standard the thickness of the coating can vary from 0.00001" to 0.005". The heat resistance capacity can be based on the coating thickness.

Comment: Dies and adhesives tend to stick well to aluminium oxide (which is on the surface of [anodized aluminium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anodizing#Anodized_aluminium)) even at room temperature.

Comment: So we're talking about the case of the phone being marred or stained by an aftermarket case. If you can add the specs of the aftermarket case that would be very helpful; there are a great many things that could leave a visible mark on just about any material's surface.

Comment: Yeah we are talking about the metal casing of the phone being stained my what I assume is some sort of foam padding to keep the phone secure. The only stats from the cases I know are what are displayed on their website. http://geckogear.com.au/products/iphone/iphone-6-plus/gecko-rugged-for-iphone-6-plus-5-5.html